# Count consecutive dates in SQL as one instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, gaps-and-islands

I would like to do a date count but count consecutive dates as one instance. In the example table below, `09/28/2013` and `09/29/2013` are consecutive therefore they count as one instance.

```
user_id      date   
------       ------ 
ABC123       09/28/2013
ABC123       09/29/2013
ABC123       09/30/2013
ABC123       10/01/2013
```

**Output:**

```
user_id      date_count   
------       ------ 
ABC123       3
```

Comment: This is pretty simple. Look at this article which explains quite clearly. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/

Comment: This is `gaps and inslands` type of queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server GROUP BY COUNT Consecutive Rows Only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735846/sql-server-group-by-count-consecutive-rows-only)

Comment: Why is your output `3` and not `1` if all the dates are consecutive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was taken from [Sean Lange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange) comment.  His link ([HERE](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/)) was spot on to what you need.  The final code from the link was...

```
WITH
cteGroupedDates AS
( --=== Find the unique dates and assign them to a group.
 -- The group looks like a date but the date means nothing except that adjacent
 -- dates will be a part of the same group.
SELECT UniqueDate = SomeDate,
    DateGroup  = DATEADD(dd, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeDate), SomeDate)
FROM #MyHead
GROUP BY SomeDate
)
--===== Now, if we find the MIN and MAX date for each DateGroup, we'll have the
 -- Start and End dates of each group of contiguous daes.  While we're at it,
 -- we can also figure out how many days are in each range of days.
SELECT StartDate = MIN(UniqueDate),
    EndDate   = MAX(UniqueDate),
    Days      = DATEDIFF(dd,MIN(UniqueDate),MAX(UniqueDate))+1
FROM cteGroupedDates
GROUP BY DateGroup
ORDER BY StartDate
;
```

**Making some name changes to try and make it easier to understand...**

```
WITH
dateGroup AS
( --This is used to distinguish the different continuous sets of dates    
SELECT UniqueDate = date,
    DateGroup  = DATEADD(dd, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date), date)
FROM userdate
GROUP BY date
)

--Using dateGroup to get the groups of dates we can utilize it to get the count for them
SELECT StartDate = MIN(UniqueDate),
    EndDate   = MAX(UniqueDate),
    Days      = DATEDIFF(dd,MIN(UniqueDate),MAX(UniqueDate))+1,
    u.user_id
FROM dateGroup JOIN userdate u ON u.date = UniqueDate
GROUP BY DateGroup, u.user_id
ORDER BY StartDate
;
```

I added `JOIN userdate u ON u.date = UniqueDate` after the `FROM dateCount` to get the user ID.  Also added `u.user_id` to the group by.  Wouldn't work because `u.user_id` is in the SELECT (need information in the SELECT in the GROUP BY).

**Data From Table:**

[image: Data From Table]

**Proof:**

[image: Proof]

**----------EDIT 1----------**

I am going to take a guess at what you truly want!

This is what I came up.  Two different queries both with the same results.

**First query:**

```
WITH
dateGroup AS
( --This is used to distinguish the different continuous sets of dates    
SELECT UniqueDate = date,
DateGroup  = DATEADD(dd, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date), date),
user_id
FROM userdate
GROUP BY date, user_id
),
userIDGroup AS
( --This is used to get the previous table that you saw in my original answer
SELECT COUNT(d.user_id) as 'Instances',
d.user_id
FROM dateGroup d
GROUP BY DateGroup, d.user_id
)

SELECT
COUNT(u.user_id) AS 'Instances',
u.user_id
FROM userIDGroup u
GROUP BY u.user_id
;
```

**Second Query (the one that I also prefer):**

```
WITH
dateGroup AS
( --This is used to distinguish the different continuous sets of dates    
SELECT UniqueDate = date,
DateGroup  = DATEADD(dd, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date), date),
user_id
FROM userdate
GROUP BY date, user_id
)

SELECT count(c.user_id) AS 'Instances', c.user_id
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(d.user_id) as 'Instances',
d.user_id
FROM dateGroup d
GROUP BY DateGroup, d.user_id
) c GROUP BY c.user_id
;
```

**Proof:**

[image]

Comment: Not quite what I need. All I want is a count of dates, but all consecutive date blocks should count as 1 instance. I don't need the number of days in a date bock. For example Jan 1, Jan 2, Jan 3 count as 1. Sorry if I am not explaining this clearly.

Comment: @Filip No you did explain that fine in the question.  I just forgot about it when I looked at the link.  In your question shouldn't your output be 1?  Since there is only one block?  What I am a little confused on is your output.  Do you want the total count of "consecutive date blocks"?

Comment: I want the total count of "consecutive date blocks" plus any other dates that are there for that specific user_id

Comment: @Filip I have an edit in my answer (edit 1).  My original answer showed all of the blocks. My edit has the count for each one for each user:)

Answer (score 0):

Calling your source table `users_and_dates`, the below will drop any date where the next day is also in the data set.

```
select t1.user_id, 
    count(*)
from users_and_dates t1
join users_and_dates t2
    on t1.user_id=t2.user_id
        and t1.date+1=t2.date
where t2.user_id is null
```